# HOW can I make header only on the first page?

Tags: header-footer, texmaker

I have this preamble

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {LaTeX/} } 
\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Logo}}
\fancyfoot[L]{} 
\fancyfoot[C]{} 
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
```

The Logo is also showing on the other pages. HOW can I make header only on the first page?

Comment: I would assume `\thispagestyle{fancy}` on the relevant page only?

Comment: Where should I place it?

Comment: @AlimTeacher: Of course at the position where the content starts for the relevant page, with `\clearpage` before, eventually

Comment: Is your first page a title page? if so: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)

Comment: Or define the head empty after the first page: `\fancyhead[C]{}`

Comment: Without more information, all of us can only guess what is going on. Please elaborate a bit on what's up.

Comment: Okay my documentclass is \documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

Comment: so my first page is not a title page

Comment: I think I solved it

Comment: The use of `fancyhdr` along with a KOMA class is heavily discouraged. Please substitute with the very own `scrlayer-scrpage`.